# Existence of representation of symmetry transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, hilbert-space

There is a simple fact that we can change our point of view and that physical laws should remain the same, id est, outcomes of our experiments should be the same no matter from which frame of reference we are observing. So, there is a physical state that changes under the change of our point of view and there is a new wave function which describes it. Should there be a representation of this transformation which takes the old wave function into new one? Is there any proof of such a claim? Should there always be transformation of wave function for every transformation of the physical system? Space-time coordinates are transformed of course, but what about the state itself? Is there any proof of this?

Comment: That is only true for inertial observers.

Comment: Of course, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner's_theorem) every symmetry is represented as a unitary or anti-unitary operator upon the Hilbert space of states.

Comment: Man, lol, tnx. You know I am reading this chapter in Weinberg book on QFT and at he and of it there is an apendix and in it, Wigner theorem. So, I rush here to say, its fine, I found what is buging me....and there it is, your answer. :-)  Any ways, I was thinking of how to prove this without looing at the apendix...

Comment: By myself...trying to be a genius...